# Header not visible in UITableView Controller

Tags: ios, uitableview

> In my table view, i am setting the header title. But its not visible,
>   i have to drag down the view to see and when i release it gets hidden
>   and only the rows are visible. I want the header to be visible by
>   default.
>
> Here's the table view delegates i use:

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    // Return the number of sections.
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    // Return the number of rows in the section.
    return [arrayUseCases count];
}

- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    return 60; //row height
}

- (NSString *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView titleForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section {

    return @"General Cases";
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"UseCasesCell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];
    UIView *bgColorView = [[UIView alloc] init];
    // Configure the cell...

    bgColorView.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:90.0f / 255.0f green:120.0f / 255.0f blue:190.0f / 255.0f alpha:1.0f];
    bgColorView.layer.masksToBounds = YES;
    [cell setSelectedBackgroundView:bgColorView];

    NSString *rpcName = [self.arrayUseCases objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]];

    [[cell textLabel] setText:rpcName];
    [[cell textLabel] setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"ChalkBoard SE" size:18]];
    cell.textLabel.textColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:90.0f / 255.0f green:120.0f / 255.0f blue:190.0f / 255.0f alpha:1.0f];


    return cell;
}

#pragma mark - Table view delegate

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    NSLog(@"Clicked table view in GeneralUseCase View");
    UIStoryboard * storyBoard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryboard" bundle:nil];

    [[self navigationController] pushViewController:[storyBoard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"LogViewID"] animated:YES];

    NSIndexPath *index = [self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow];

    dic = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys:index,@"Index", nil];

    [self performSelector:@selector(postUseCaseNotification) withObject:nil afterDelay:1.0];

    //to deselect the selected row when view comes back
    [tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:[tableView indexPathForSelectedRow] animated:NO];

    //    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:LogViewControllerGeneralUseCaseNotification object:self userInfo:dic];


}
```

Comment: Have you tried adding heightForHeaderInSection method and returning a height? Its under UITableViewDelegate.

Comment: I tried it. Adding that it further hides the visible rows. 
I am using this in tabview (2 tabs), same code in both the tabs. For one its fine, without the heightForHeaderInSection.

Comment: Ok. Now i gave the return value >100. Its fine :)
But I dont have this delegate in the other tableview controller and it displays the header fine. I am not sure why though ?!

Comment: Can you vote up my answer?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Please add this method:

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
     return 100;
}
```

Answer (score 7):

Set the table view header height

```
-(CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
   return 40; // What ever height you want.
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You forgot to implement this method (tableView:heightForHeader:) - which returns the height of the header. Otherwise it returns 0 and that's why it is not rendered:

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return 40; // or whatever height you want
}
```

Comment: @iOSDeveloper so why the answered time is later than mine?:)